# DispatchTimer bind to button

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a code that gets download output on click of the button in WPF C#.
Now I would like to create timer so that once user asks for download status the timer starts and provides real time status by ticking that function every few seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a Timer to your form. start timer in the click event of the button, when the file downloaded then call stop method of the timer.

in the class declare a variable as StartTime;
DateTime StartTime;

in the click wite something like this

```
StartTime = DateTime.Now;
```

in Tick event of the timer write this:

```
myTimer.Enabled = true;
myTimer.Start();
var elapsedTime = (DateTime.Now - StartTime).TotalMiliseconds;
```

After completing the download request:

```
myTimer.Stop();
myTimer.Enabled = False;
```